# How can I get only 1 row in Solr? "start" and "rows" isn't helpful for me

Tags: solr

I'm finding a way to get only 1 row from solr not using "start" and "rows", if query returns more than 1 row. I know those makes me possible to get 1 row, but it eventually resulted in returning all rows internally. Of course it's better to add some conditions but there is no effective query to extract. Is there any possible way?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? _Why_ isn't it helpful? `rows` would be the way to do just that, and depending on what you want to do (and how you do it), Lucene might have to look at many documents to do whatever you're trying to do. Instead describe what your actual issue/problem is. Is it slow? Are you sorting by a field? Do you require all the information returned? Can you use just docValues as stored instead of retrieving the actual content of the documents? etc.

Comment: I have an problem of performance. I mean that, in your words, it is slow. And yes, sorting by a field, plus, I need all information returned. In this situation , docValue is a solution? I'm newbie to Solr so I'm not sure how it resolves my problem. Changing 
 the content of "schema.xm"l may not be possible due to circumstances. though.

Comment: Why do you think that the number of documents through `rows` to be returned is the problem? If you're sorting by a field, that sort will have to look at the index for that field to determine which documents to include anyway. Maybe the field cache or something else is a better strategy? How much content is in the fields being returned? Have you tried using a different response writer (.. for a single document it won't matter much, but for a larger result set...). What kind of response times are you looking at that is too slow? Have you check the debug / explain output for your query?

Comment: And are we talking about a clustered situation? Are you only returning a single document from the beginning of the result set? Do you use `start` at all?